# Issue with score in game with unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my game the player have to collect a coins. The problem is that when player dies and starts a new game, the number of coins is not reset. For example:

starting new game and collectiong 15 coins, then dies

starting new game and number of coins i set to 15, not 0

How can I fix that??

Script used for displaying score on the screen:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    Coin coin;
    void Update()
    {
        coin = FindObjectOfType<Coin>();
        GetComponent<Text>().text = coin.GetScore().ToString();
    }
```

Script used for adding coins to score:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Coin : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed = 10f;
    public static int score = 0;
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        score += 1;
    }
    public int GetScore()
    {
        return score;
    }
}
```

I also need to say that I was messin around with PlayerPrefs with that score to make some highscore concept, but I deleted every PlayerPrefs I did. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please read [ask] and make sure your title properly covers your question. "Issue with score" is unclear.

Answer (score 5):

This is the problematic line:

```
public static int score = 0;
```

A variable declared "static" will last for as long as the runtime does, even if the object it's tied to is destroyed (it's a value shared across *all* coin objects).

Ideally, you'd make it non-static (which is what Unity expects).

```
public int score = 0;
```

If you then re-create the Coin object whenever the player dies, unity will handle the cleanup for you.

Alternatively, you could add a "Reset" method to the Coin class...

```
public int GetScore()
{
    return score;
}

public void Reset()
{
    score = 0;
}
```

I [answered a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/187095/refactoring-a-unity-script-into-two-and-reading-variables-in-one-from-the-other/187098#187098) which goes into statics in more detail and may be of interest.

> Normally when a class has variables, every time you make a new instance of the class, it gets its own copies of each variable.
>
> (You can create two `Animal` classes and give each one a different `Name`)
>
> A `static` variable is different. Instead of each instance having its own copy of the variable, they all share the same one.
>
> So if you set `animal1.StaticName`, you'd change `animal2.StaticName` as well. More to the point, you don't even need to make an animal, you can just set `Animal.StaticName` directly.
>
> So... A static variable can be read/set (and static methods can be executed) even if you haven't created an instance of the class.

Oh and... If you *do* decide to keep the score static, you don't need to find a specific object to get the score...

```
void Update()
{
    GetComponent<Text>().text = Coin.score.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i used static because i have multiple coin objects(they are instantiating)

Comment: when I set score non-static then every time a player collects coin it goes up to 1 and again goes down to 0

Comment: So each coin is responsible for tracking its own score? Why not just give the player a "Score" property that increases by 1 every time they touch a coin? Then a new player comes with a new score of `0`. Failing that, if you want to preserve your current design, implement the `Reset()` method as demonstrated and call it when your player dies

Comment: But your code at present is taking a very long-winded approach... Find ALL coins in the scene, pick one at random and then ask it what the shared coin total is. Every frame. By making `score` a static on `Coin`, you're saying "score is a property that applies to all coins" which isn't _really_ correct.

Comment: Yes, you are right I did like you said - refactored code and made `score` as a player property, thanks for that